# Reorder Elements Inside Container Explicitly by Number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a container, `#charts`, which has some elements inside it like this:

```html
<div id="charts">
    <div id="column"></div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="line"></div>
    <div id="pie"></div>
</div>
```

... how can I reorder them with JavaScript *explicitly by specifying an index to which to change*? Consider the following pseudo-code:

```js
$("#charts").find("#column").order(3);
```

What I want this to do is take into account the other elements in the container and reposition this certain element accordingly. I will be reordering them all at once so that may be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plain js example:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('charts'),
    divs = container.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    target = document.getElementById('column');

container.insertBefore(target, divs[3]);
```

Comment: Nice, straightforward solution but I improved it slightly. See the edits! Thanks.